# What does exactly name of 2D array represents?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Like name of 1D array represents address of a[0], what does name of 2D array represents?
If it also represents address of a[0][0], then why
I get error using this :

```
int a[2][2];
sort(a,a+4);
```

While,

```
sort(&a[0][0] , &a[0][0]+4)
```

works perfectly fine.

Comment: A pointer to the first element (after decay)

Comment: Can you post the error? `a+4` is by far out of bounds, do you mean `a+2` as pointer to the end?

Comment: 2D arrays are simply 1D arrays of 1D arrays. They behave exactly the same as any other 1D arrays: `a == &a[0]`. (Note that the type of `&a[0]` is `int (*)[2]` in this case.)

Comment: The reason why sort(a, a+4) compiles  at all is that an array decays to the address of it's first element even if it has multiple dimensions. So `a` becomes `&a[0][0]`. But not so with `a+4` as that is the same as `a[4]` and `a[4]` then decays to `&a[4][0]` or `&a[0][0]+8`, which should make it clear why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of `1D` array like

```
int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

`arr` means array name and it represents base address of `arr`. And `arr` and address of `arr[0]` is same.

Similarly in case of `2D` array like

```
int arr[2][2] = { {1,2},{3,4}};
```

`arr` means array name and it represents base address of `arr`.

```
printf("%p\n",(void*)arr);
printf("%p\n",(void*)&arr[0]);
printf("%p\n",(void*)&arr[0][0]);
```

Above all `printf()` results in same output.

**Note :** In below case

```
int a[2][2];
sort(a,a+4);
```

`a+4` doesn't exists at all, you have only `a+0` and `a+1`.

```
a[0][0]     a[0][1]     a[1][0]     a[1][1]
  |(0x100)    |(0x104)   |(0x108)     |(0x10c)
  -------------           ------------    
        |                    |
       a[0](0x100)          a[1](0x108) or a+1 ... there is no a+4
        |                    |
        ----------------------   
                 |
                 a (0x100<- assume base address of 2D array a is ox100)
```

While `&a[0][0]+4` is different, it is  `(0x100 + 4 * sizeof(a[0][0])` i.e `0x110(in hexa)`.

Answer (score 0):

A 2D array is an array of arrays and works in exactly the same way as a 1D array:

```
int a[10];
a == &a[0];
int* = &a[0];

int b[10][20];
b == &b[0];
int** = &b[0];
```

The name of a 2D array is equivalent to a pointer to the first element of the outer array which is the inner 1D array.